# Can dapper deserialize json stored as text?

Tags: c#, json, dapper

```
public class MyType
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int[] MyArray { get; set; }
}

var sql = "SELECT id, MyArrayAsJson as MyArray";
var x = await connection.QueryAsync<MyType>(sql);
```

I have a string stored in the database which looks like json: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

When I query the db with Dapper, I would like dapper to deserialize to an object, MyType. Dapper wants MyArrayAsJson to be a string because it is, but I want it to deserialize to an int array. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure, but couldn't you simply return result as IEnumerable<string> then use Newtonsoft?

Comment: @Greg Dapper is the one that would have to do that. Apparently I can't instruct it to do so

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but what I mean is couldn't you have MSSQL return JSON into a single column, then use Newtonsoft to deserialize the JSON into your desired object since MSSQL 2016 can translate tabular data into JSON.

Comment: @Greg Yeah, that's essentially what I ended up doing but I ended up having to make a 2nd "model" to do that. One with a `string` and one with an `int[]` as the type, so it was just a little additional work that I was hoping to avoid. In the end, it was the right way to do it though. Also, this is mariadb 10.1, not mssql :)

Comment: Yeah, when I researched that approach it seemed like it might be more work unless you are returning Json directly to a SPA via an API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dapper wants nothing to do with your fancy serialization shenanigans :) Basically, no: read it from the database as a string, *then* deserialize.

Adding an API that provided more direct / raw access to the incoming data as a BLOB/CLOB sequence would be nice, but it doesn't exist in Dapper today.

Comment: Given your role in this, your answer being a few years old and the added/newer answers: Would you still recommend "read as string, _then_ deserialize"?

Comment: @asons yes, but people are free to choose other options

Answer (score 16):

```
public class JsonTypeHandler : SqlMapper.ITypeHandler
{
    public void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, object value)
    {
        parameter.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public object Parse(Type destinationType, object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value as string, destinationType);
    }
}


SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(int[]), new JsonTypeHandler());
```

Comment: Nice. Is this a newer feature?

Comment: @JoePhillips (IMHO) I think you should set this answer as the best answer for the question.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, `IDbDataParameter` is in `System.Data`.

Answer (score 4):

Dapper cannot do that, but **you can do that!**

It is just a little work using [Dapper Multi Mapping](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#multi-mapping)

Select your `[JsonColumn]` as a string, and while mapping the results deserialize the JSON column, for example, if you have a `Foo` class and you want to deserialize the `[JsonColumn]` to it, do that:

```
using (var db = _context.Connect())
{
    return await db.QueryAsync<Foo, string, Foo>(query, (foo, jsonColumnString) =>
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(jsonColumnString);
    },
    splitOn: "JsonColumn",
    param: parameters);
}
```