# How to map JSON from bank in Dapper using C # dictionary?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, dictionary, dapper

I have a MySQL database and I have a JSON column that stores items as follows:

```
[{"key":"value"},{"key2","value2"},...}
```

How can I handle this and load into a C # dictionary?
I'm getting error converting from string to dictionary

Example of model:

```
public class Person
{
  string name;
  Dictionary<string, string> itens;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can dapper deserialize json stored as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888334/can-dapper-deserialize-json-stored-as-text)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select it. [Dapper does not support this out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49888452/2526818). Then you could use Newtonsoft.JSON ([NuGet-Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)) and use it's deserializer like so:

```
myPerson.itens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Reference: 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm

Comment: How would that look in Dapper's query?

Comment: You should first read the json from database and then deserialize as shown, Marc Gravel approves: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888334/can-dapper-deserialize-json-stored-as-text

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Custom Handler. I've written detailed articles on that subject.

- https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-type-handling-4b447b97c620
- https://medium.com/dapper-net/one-to-many-mapping-with-dapper-55ae6a65cfd4

Samples are also available on GitHub:

https://github.com/yorek/dapper-samples

I've used SQL Server as RDBMS, but everything should apply as is to MySQL

Answer (score -1):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dir = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                    string splitOn = "value";


                    dir = cnn.Query<string, string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>("YOUR_SP", (s, i) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, i), null, null, false, splitOn, null, null)
        .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```